# Android error- using seprate Listner Class

Tags: android

i'm new to android programming and i'm making a program that Changes the color of textview when button or radio button is pressed. and even i am writing a seprate Listner class for this.Now In both activity and listner class and activity it is showing an error.Both my activity class and Listner class is been attched here

Main Activity-error shown in all buttons and ration button of `ColorSetter(b1.setOnClickListener(new ColorSetter(Color.RED, this));`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private View mColorRegion;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mColorRegion = findViewById(R.id.color_region);
    Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button b3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

            RadioButton r1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio_button1);
            RadioButton r2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio_button2);
            RadioButton r3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio_button3);

            b1.setOnClickListener(new ColorSetter(Color.RED, this));
            b2.setOnClickListener(new ColorSetter(Color.BLUE, this));
            b3.setOnClickListener(new ColorSetter(Color.YELLOW, this));
            r1.setOnClickListener(new ColorSetter(Color.RED, this));
            r2.setOnClickListener(new ColorSetter(Color.BLUE, this));
            r3.setOnClickListener(new ColorSetter(Color.YELLOW, this));

    }

    public void setRegionColor(int color) {
    mColorRegion.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }
}
```

Listner-plz explain how to write this seprate listner

```
public class ColorSetter implements OnClickListener {

private int regionColor;
private Events1Example mainActivity;
public ColorSetter(int regionColor,Events1Example mainActivity) {
        this.regionColor = regionColor;
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
        }

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    mainActivity.setRegionColor(regionColor);

}

}
```

Comment: what error you r gettig?

Comment: Can you try to explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @user3041524 i have posted sample code if its not understandable please let me know

Answer (score 1):

i hope this is what you expected .check this type of code.

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private View mColorRegion;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mColorRegion = findViewById(R.id.color_region);
    Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button b3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

    RadioButton r1 =
            (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio_button1);
            RadioButton r2 =
            (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio_button2);
            RadioButton r3 =
            (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio_button3);

            b1.setOnClickListener(new ColorSetter(Color.RED, this));
            b2.setOnClickListener(new ColorSetter(Color.BLUE, this));
            b3.setOnClickListener(new ColorSetter(Color.YELLOW, this));
            r1.setOnClickListener(new ColorSetter(Color.RED, this));
            r2.setOnClickListener(new ColorSetter(Color.BLUE, this));
            r3.setOnClickListener(new ColorSetter(Color.YELLOW, this));

}
public void setRegionColor(int color) {
    mColorRegion.setBackgroundColor(color);
}
}


Button.OnClickListener btnOnClickListener=new Button.OnClickListener()
               {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {




                    if(v==b1)
                    {

                       //b1 code goes here

                    }
                    else if(v==cb2)
                    {
                        //b2 code goes here
                    }


               };
```

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
private Events1Example mainActivity;
public ColorSetter(int regionColor,Events1Example mainActivity) {
```

into

```
private MainActivity mainActivity;
public ColorSetter(int regionColor,MainActivity mainActivity) {
```